# Large data processing (AWK)

Tags: awk

I have filtered some important data from a main file such as the one in figure 1 and I have obtained at the end one such as in figure 2. The thing is that I have done that using multiple commands such as:

```
awk '{gsub("ndn.InterestLifetime=2000&ndn.Nonce", ""); print $1,$2,$3,$10,$11,$12}'
awk 'NF'
awk -F':' -v OFS='=' '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8}'
awk '{if($6 =="") {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6="0", $7} else {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}}'
awk '{if($4 == "D" ) {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7="\t""\t""1024", $8} else{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7="\t""24", $8}}'
awk '{printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-16s %-10s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}'
```

All of these commands I run one by one in the console to obtain the final output but at this moment I have approximately 100files to analyze.

Is there a possible way to merge all these commands into a single script to go from figure 1 to figure 2 in just one step?

Thanks!

**Note:** Some characters I had to remove it by hand because when gsub was applied it removed also characters that shouldn't be removed.
Figure 1:

```
   + 0 /NodeList/0/DeviceList/0/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/TxQueue/Enqueue ns3::PppHeader (Point-to-Point Protocol: NDN (0x0077)) ns3::ndn::Interest (I: /prefix/%FE%00?ndn.InterestLifetime=2000&ndn.Nonce=3506978425)
   - 0 /NodeList/0/DeviceList/0/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/TxQueue/Dequeue ns3::PppHeader (Point-to-Point Protocol: NDN (0x0077)) ns3::ndn::Interest (I: /prefix/%FE%00?ndn.InterestLifetime=2000&ndn.Nonce=3506978425)
   + 0.0020224 /NodeList/1/DeviceList/1/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/TxQueue/Enqueue ns3::PppHeader (Point-to-Point Protocol: NDN (0x0077)) ns3::ndn::Interest (I: /prefix/%FE%00?ndn.InterestLifetime=2000&ndn.Nonce=3506978425)
   - 0.0020224 /NodeList/1/DeviceList/1/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/TxQueue/Dequeue ns3::PppHeader (Point-to-Point Protocol: NDN (0x0077)) ns3::ndn::Interest (I: /prefix/%FE%00?ndn.InterestLifetime=2000&ndn.Nonce=3506978425)
   r 0.0020224 /NodeList/1/DeviceList/0/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/MacRx ns3::PppHeader (Point-to-Point Protocol: NDN (0x0077)) ns3::ndn::Interest (I: /prefix/%FE%00?ndn.InterestLifetime=2000&ndn.Nonce=3506978425)
   r 0.0040448 /NodeList/2/DeviceList/0/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/MacRx ns3::PppHeader (Point-to-Point Protocol: NDN (0x0077)) ns3::ndn::Interest (I: /prefix/%FE%00?ndn.InterestLifetime=2000&ndn.Nonce=3506978425)
   + 0.0040448 /NodeList/2/DeviceList/0/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/TxQueue/Enqueue ns3::PppHeader (Point-to-Point Protocol: NDN (0x0077)) ns3::ndn::Data (D: Name: /prefix/%FE%00

    MetaInfo: ContentType: 0, FreshnessPeriod: 0 milliseconds
   Content: (size: 1024)
   Signature: (type: 255, value_length: 0)
   )

    - 0.0040448 /NodeList/2/DeviceList/0/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/TxQueue/Dequeue ns3::PppHeader (Point-to-Point Protocol: NDN (0x0077)) ns3::ndn::Data (D: Name: /prefix/%FE%00
   MetaInfo: ContentType: 0, FreshnessPeriod: 0 milliseconds
   Content: (size: 1024)
   Signature: (type: 255, value_length: 0)
   )
```

`Figure 2:

```
   +          0          /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%00    3911074054       24        
   -          0          /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%00    3911074054       24        
   +          0.01       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%01    2369863103       24        
   -          0.01       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%01    2369863103       24        
   +          0.02       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%02    1645723821       24        
   -          0.02       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%02    1645723821       24        
   +          0.03       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%03    3521946681       24        
   -          0.03       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%03    3521946681       24        
   +          0.04       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%04    471669802        24        
   -          0.04       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%04    471669802        24        
   +          0.05       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%05    2273949020       24        
   -          0.05       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%05    2273949020       24        
   +          0.06       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%06    2325138250       24        
   -          0.06       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%06    2325138250       24        
   +          0.07       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%07    3740802279       24        
   -          0.07       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%07    3740802279       24        
   +          0.08       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%08    745982218        24        
   -          0.08       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%08    745982218        24        
   +          0.09       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%09    2174891134       24        
   -          0.09       /NodeList/10/ I          /%FE%09    2174891134`       24
```

Comment: you could just start all separate awk commands at the same time, piped together. awk '.......' inputfile1 | awk '....' | ..etc. | awk '......' > outputfile1

Comment: Your `awk` commands, when put into a pipeline, do not produce anything resembling `Figure 2`.